# how to create diagonal galleries/banners that move on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, gallery

I'm trying to create a diagonal gallery that moves with scroll, but when I scroll too fast the sliders (pictures) don't return to their positions, I tried to solve this problem, but it doesn't look good, the pictures have to return to a position when I scroll up or down without getting disordered.

examples:
https://www.env.studio/
https://3rcore.com/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Locomotive scrolling</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="container__gallery">

            <div class="slide__1">
                <div class="img1">
                </div>
                <div class="img2">
                </div>
                <div class="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="img4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide__2">
                <div class="img2"></div>
                <div class="img4">
                </div>
                <div class="img1">
                </div>
                <div class="img3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide__3">
                <div class="img1">
                </div>
                <div class="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="img2">
                </div>
                <div class="img4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide__4">
                <div class="img4">
                </div>
                <div class="img1">
                </div>

                <div class="img2">
                </div>
                <div class="img3">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-top: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container__gallery{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
}


.slide__1, .slide__2, .slide__3, .slide__4{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 140%;
    height: 40%;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    transform: skew(-10deg) rotateZ(20deg);
}

.slide__1{
    top: -37px;
    right: -830px;
    transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.slide__2{
    top: 10px;
    right: -190px;
    transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.slide__3{
    top: 400px;
    right: -430px;
    transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.slide__4{
    top: 568px;
    right: -100px;
    transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.img1{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    background-image: url("https://static.fundacion-affinity.org/cdn/farfuture/PVbbIC-0M9y4fPbbCsdvAD8bcjjtbFc0NSP3lRwlWcE/mtime:1643275542/sites/default/files/los-10-sonidos-principales-del-perro.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.img2{
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url("https://media.glamour.mx/photos/6529b544daab1b14402e2b34/16:9/w_2992,h_1683,c_limit/qu%C3%A9-significa-encontrarte-con-un-gato-negro-en-viernes-13-.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.img3{
    background-color: crimson;
    background-image: url("https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/796e6c9/2147483647/strip/true/crop/1970x1108+39+0/resize/1200x675!/quality/75/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2F12%2Fa5%2F79e097ccf62312d18a025f22ce48%2Fhoyla-recuento-11-cosas-aman-gatos-top-001");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.img4{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/descubren-que-los-humanos-influimos-en-el-color-de-ojos-de-los-perros-1280x720.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```
const element = document.querySelector('.container__gallery')
const slider1 = document.querySelector('.slide__1')
const slider2 = document.querySelector('.slide__2')
const slider3 = document.querySelector('.slide__3')
const slider4 = document.querySelector('.slide__4')

let lastScrollTop = 0

let control = {
    top1: -37,
    right1: -830,
    top2: 10,
    right2: -190,
    top3: 400,
    right3: -430,
    top4: 350,
    right4: 460,
}

const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '600px',
    threshold: 0.05
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
observer.observe(element)

function validateScrolling(){

    const currentScrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const isScrollingDown = currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop;
    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    return isScrollingDown;
}

function move(isScrollingDown){
    // Definir el ángulo en radianes (20 grados)
    const anguloRadianes = 158.72 * (Math.PI / 180);
    const scale = 0.01;
    let deltaX = 0
    let deltaY = 0
    const scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

    if(!(isScrollingDown ===false && scrollY <= 200 && scrollY >= 122))
        // Calcular el cambio en las coordenadas X e Y utilizando funciones trigonométricas
        deltaX = scrollY * Math.cos(anguloRadianes) * scale;
        deltaY = scrollY * Math.sin(anguloRadianes) * scale;



    return {deltaX, deltaY}
}

function scrollerEvent(){

    let isScrollingDown = validateScrolling()
    let delta = move(isScrollingDown)

    if(isScrollingDown == false && scrollY <= 200 && scrollY >= 120){

        control.right1 = -830;
        control.top1 = -37;

        control.right2 = -190;
        control.top2 = 10;

        control.right3 = -430 ;
        control.top3 = 400 ;

        control.right4 = 460;
        control.top4 = 350;

        slider1.style.right = control.right1 + "px";
        slider1.style.top = control.top1 + "px";

        slider2.style.right = control.right2 + "px";
        slider2.style.top = control.top2 + "px";

        slider3.style.right = control.right3 + "px";
        slider3.style.top = control.top3 + "px";

        slider4.style.right = control.right4 + "px";
        slider4.style.top = control.top4 + "px";
    }
    else if(isScrollingDown == false && scrollY <= 1000 && scrollY >= 977){

        control.right1 = -537.9142029413038  ;
        control.top1 = -150.7620539573103;

        control.right2 = -482.0857970586964  ;
        control.top2 = 123.7620539573103;

        control.right3 = -225.5399420589124  ;
        control.top3 = 320.36656222988285 ;

        control.right4 = 167.91420294130347;
        control.top4 = 463.76205395731006;


        slider1.style.transition = "600ms"
        slider1.style.right = control.right1 + "px";
        slider1.style.top = control.top1 + "px";
        //slider1.style.transition = "50ms"

        slider2.style.transition = "600ms"
        slider2.style.right = control.right2 + "px";
        slider2.style.top = control.top2 + "px";
        //slider2.style.transition = "50ms"

        slider3.style.transition = "600ms"
        slider3.style.right = control.right3 + "px";
        slider3.style.top = control.top3 + "px";

        slider4.style.transition = "600ms"
        slider4.style.right = control.right4 + "px";
        slider4.style.top = control.top4 + "px";
        //slider4.style.transition = "50ms"
    }
    else if (isScrollingDown){
        // Actualizar las coordenadas del objeto
        control.right1 -= delta.deltaX;
        control.top1 -= delta.deltaY;

        control.right2 += delta.deltaX;
        control.top2 += delta.deltaY;

        control.right3 -= (delta.deltaX * 0.7);
        control.top3 -= (delta.deltaY * 0.7);

        control.right4 += delta.deltaX;
        control.top4 += delta.deltaY;

        slider1.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider1.style.right = control.right1 + "px";
        slider1.style.top = control.top1 + "px";

        slider2.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider2.style.right = control.right2 + "px";
        slider2.style.top = control.top2 + "px";

        slider3.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider3.style.right = control.right3 + "px";
        slider3.style.top = control.top3 + "px";

        slider4.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider4.style.right = control.right4 + "px";
        slider4.style.top = control.top4 + "px";
    }
    else{
        // Actualizar las coordenadas del objeto

        control.right1 += delta.deltaX;
        control.top1 += delta.deltaY;

        control.right2 -= delta.deltaX;
        control.top2 -= delta.deltaY;

        control.right3 += (delta.deltaX *0.7);
        control.top3 += (delta.deltaY *0.7);

        control.right4 -= delta.deltaX;
        control.top4 -= delta.deltaY;


        slider1.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider1.style.right = control.right1 + "px";
        slider1.style.top = control.top1 + "px";

        slider2.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider2.style.right = control.right2 + "px";
        slider2.style.top = control.top2 + "px";

        slider3.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider3.style.right = control.right3 + "px";
        slider3.style.top = control.top3 + "px";

        slider4.style.transition = "50ms"
        slider4.style.right = control.right4 + "px";
        slider4.style.top = control.top4 + "px";
    }
}

function callback(entries){

    entries.forEach(entry =>{
        let intersecting = entry.isIntersecting
        if (intersecting){
            lastScrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollerEvent)
        }
        else{
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollerEvent);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a lot less code :) here is a jsfiddle doing something similar https://jsfiddle.net/ash_uncover/62tmbdp7/69/

The idea is to first display the 'slides' normally and play on rotate & scale transformations with simple values rather than using complex calculations :)

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const slide1 = document.getElementById('slide1');
const slide2 = document.getElementById('slide2');
const slide3 = document.getElementById('slide3');
const slide4 = document.getElementById('slide4');

window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  const force = container.parentElement.scrollTop / container.offsetHeight * 20
  
  slide1.style.translate = `${force}%`
  slide2.style.translate = -`${force}%`
  slide3.style.translate = `${force}%`
  slide4.style.translate = -`${force}%`
}, true)
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  rotate: 45deg;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
}

.img {
  width: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img1{
    background-image: url("https://static.fundacion-affinity.org/cdn/farfuture/PVbbIC-0M9y4fPbbCsdvAD8bcjjtbFc0NSP3lRwlWcE/mtime:1643275542/sites/default/files/los-10-sonidos-principales-del-perro.jpg");
}
.img2{
    background-image: url("https://media.glamour.mx/photos/6529b544daab1b14402e2b34/16:9/w_2992,h_1683,c_limit/qu%C3%A9-significa-encontrarte-con-un-gato-negro-en-viernes-13-.png");
}
.img3{
    background-image: url("https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/796e6c9/2147483647/strip/true/crop/1970x1108+39+0/resize/1200x675!/quality/    75/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2F12%2Fa5%2F79e097ccf62312d18a025f22ce48%2Fhoyla-recuento-11-cosas-aman-gatos-top-001");
}
.img4{
    background-image: url("https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/descubren-que-los-humanos-influimos-en-el-color-de-ojos-de-los-perros-1280x720.jpg");    
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">

  <div class="content">
    Hello scroll (top)
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-container">
      <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <div class="img img1"></div>
        <div class="img img2"></div>
        <div class="img img3"></div>
        <div class="img img4"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <div class="img img2"></div>
        <div class="img img4"></div>
        <div class="img img1"></div>
        <div class="img img3"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <div class="img img1"></div>
        <div class="img img3"></div>
        <div class="img img2"></div>
        <div class="img img4"></div>  
      </div>
      <div id="slide4" class="slide">
        <div class="img img4"></div>  
        <div class="img img1"></div>
        <div class="img img3"></div>
        <div class="img img2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    Hello scroll (bottom)
  </div>
  
</div>
```

You can play around with the rotation (set to 45deg here) and the way the 'force' variable is computed to obtain variations of the effect.